# Change the page with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I know how to use Angular Universal in my project.
I know that the first page view comes from the server side,and then, the application works like a classic Angular SPA CSR.

However, I don't undersand how the source code of the page can change when we navigate to another page (new URL), because with a classic SPA, the source code remains the same as before (I don't speak about "Inspect element"). I thank that navigating to another URL would be processed by only JS. Moreover, we don't have any loading between the pages.

Example with https://affluences.com/ using Angular Universal:

- I visit https://affluences.com/.

  - The source code corresponds to the view -> it's ok with SSR.
- I click on the card "Bibliothèques" (https://affluences.com/sites?categories=1)

  - No loading for the global page view -> The source code changes; is this page stored in cache?

Comment: Once Angular takes control, it is a normal SPA again and ‘the source’ won’t change. But that is not a problem right? A search engine spider will not ‘click’ on those links, it will simply fetch all individual pages from the server directly - so it always gets the current source..

Comment: The source code does change when navigating in the app, you see this in "View the source code of the page" (ctrl+u with Chrome).

Comment: View source might get back to the server 

Comment: When opening the source code, a new request is done ? Why it is not the case without SSR ?

Comment: It’s the same? But without ssr you always see the same source.

Comment: Why does the browser not fetch the source code in "View source" with CSR ?

Comment: Why do you assume it doesn’t?

Comment: Okay it does even with CSR ! I thank not ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MikeOne,

The "View source" is synchronized with the page view.
I thank it was the server response.